# How to integrate different vcpkg for different Visual Studio versions?

Tags: vcpkg

I have Visual Studio 2022 17.2 LTSC and 17.8 LTSC on my machine.
I want to integrate different vcpkg version for 17.2 and 17.8 separately.
How can I do that?